# Finitely generated $R$-Algebra vs finitely generated $R$-Module for $R$-Algebra $S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I have search in google a lot but could not find it.

I am confused about the following implication:

$$\text{finite}\Rightarrow \text{finite type}$$

Let $S$ be given as commutative $R$-Algebra.

$S$ is **finite** if $S$ is finitely generated as $R$-Module.

$S$ is **finite type** if $S$ is finitely generated as $R$-Algebra.

They all say trivially $R$-Module $S$ being finite implies $S$ being finite type.

Let $S$ be finite as $R$-Module then $S\cong R^{\oplus n}/M$ for some $n$ and $M$ submodule of $R^{\oplus n}$

I can't understand how this clearly implies $S\cong R[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]/I$ as $R$ algebra for some $I$ ideal of $R[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$

If $S=\langle s_1,\cdots,s_n\rangle$ then since $S$ is a $R$-Algebra

then $f:R\to S$ extends $\tilde f:R[s_1,\dots,s_n]\to S$ surjectively?

Answer (score 4):

Consider a set $Q \subseteq S$.

Suppose $Q$ generates $S$ as an $R$-module. Then I claim $Q$ also generates $S$ as an $R$-algebra.

For suppose we have some sub-$R$-algebra $A \subseteq S$ such that $Q \subseteq A$. Then we see that $A$ is also a sub-$R$-module of $S$, and $Q \subseteq A$. Therefore, citing the fact that $Q$ generates $S$ as a module, we can conclude that $A = S$. Thus, we see that $Q$ generates $S$ as an $R$-algebra.

In particular, then, when $S$ is finite, we can take $Q$ to be a finite set. Then $Q$ is also a finite set which generates $S$ as an algebra, so $S$ is of finite type.

We can rephrase the proof in terms of free modules and free algebras. Suppose there is a surjective $R$-module homomorphism $f : R^{\oplus n} \to S$ (this is equivalent to postulating some isomorphism $S \cong R^{\oplus n} / M$). Then let $g : R^{\oplus n} \to R[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ be the unique $R$-linear map sending $e_i$ to $x_i$ for all $i$. And let $h : R[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \to S$ be the unique $R$-algebra homomorphism sending $x_i$ to $f(e_i)$ for all $i$.

Then for all $i$, we have $h(g(e_i)) = h(x_i) = f(e_i)$, and both $h \circ g$ and $f$ are linear; therefore, $h \circ g = f$.

Since $f$ is surjective and $f = h \circ g$, we see that $h$ must also be surjective. That is, there is some surjective $R$-algebra morphism $R[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \to S$. This is equivalent to postulating some isomorphism $S \cong R[x_1, \ldots, x_n] / I$.